# "Transform geometry" Node does not affect the texture

Tags: geometry-nodes

Hi could someone please show me a simple solution to fix this in blender 4.0?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hi. As you can see when I set the material in geometry nodes its perfectly centered. But when I rotate it, it stays at the same horizontal direction. It seems gradient texture node in shading editor creates a bounding box around the object and doesn't matter if you rotate it or not it will create that bounding box and scale it down or up to keep the texture at the center of object.

**Solution :**

Thanks to Chris I Fixed it . I used "Store named attribute" and linked it to "separate XYZ" and "Scale" Node and finally to "UV Map" socket. In the shading editor I deleted "Mapping" and "Texture Coordinate" Nodes and added the "Attribute" node. The Problem is I don't understand the concept. Why is this working?

[image]
[image]

**I have two questions**

**1)** Is this the only way to do it?

**2)** Why *Shading editor* and *Geometry nodes* need attributes to talk to each other?

*I am really sorry for bombarding this forum with my rookie questions.*

Comment: Hi. As you can see when I set the material in geometry nodes its perfectly centered. But when I rotate it, it stays at the same horizontal direction. It seems gradient texture node in shading editor creates a bounding box around the object and doesn't matter if you rotate it or not it will create that bounding box and scale it down or up to keep the texture at the center of object.

Comment: I suggest you copy that comment into your question rather than just adding it as a comment! You can edit your question with the [Edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/310311/edit) link below it, add your text, and the question will be resubmitted automatically.

Comment: next time please add blend file so we don't have to rebuild everything manually, thx.

Comment: Thanks @JohnEason I did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use uv coordinates instead of generated.

[image]

UV Sphere works e.g. with object coordinates like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Chris  I tried it but it didn't work. I've deleted the group input and replaced it with a UV sphere. Is it why its not working?

Comment: i updated my answer